# Java Jdbc Insert

Tags: java

I'm doing a sample project using jdbc driver. My problem is if I enter a null in my 2 textfield. The null should not be load into the database? Is there anyway how to avoid inserting a empty field in database? Any help will appreciate.

```
//Execute a query
System.out.println("Creating Statement..");
String query = "INSERT INTO INFO (FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME) VALUES (?,?)";
myStatement = con.prepareStatement(query);

myStatement.setString(1, firstnameTf.getText());
myStatement.setString(2, lastnameTf.getText());
myStatement.executeUpdate();

if (firstnameTf.getText().isEmpty() || lastnameTf.getText().isEmpty()){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Insert");
}

myStatement.close();
con.close();
```

Comment: What is the schema for the table `INFO`? The simplest way is to declare the names as `NOT NULL` - you will get an exception if you try to insert `null`.

Comment: Add `NOT NULL` check in database it will throw an exception and catch it in catch block and print any msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use this

```
if (firstnameTf.getText().isEmpty() || lastnameTf.getText().isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please Insert");
    } 



else{
          myStatement =con.prepareStatement(query);

           myStatement.setString(1,firstnameTf.getText());
           myStatement.setString(2, lastnameTf.getText());
           myStatement.executeUpdate();}
```